# SwiftUI - JSON from GitHub REST API fails to parse

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, github-api

I am attempting to create an app in SwiftUI using GitHub's REST API. I am attempting to only retrieve only the login name and profile picture of a given user's followers and then populate a `List`.

***FollowersView.swift***

```
import SwiftUI

struct Follower: Codable, Hashable {
    public var login:      String
    public var avatar_url:  String
}

struct Response: Codable {
    var followers: [Follower] = [Follower]()
}

struct FollowersView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var followerInfo: FollowerInfo
    @State var followers: [Follower] = [Follower]()
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                List(followers, id: \.self) { follower in
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                      Image(decorative: "\(follower.avatar_url).png")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                        HStack(spacing: 5) {
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                            Text("\(follower.login)").fontWeight(.heavy)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(perform: loadData)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("\(followerInfo.followerUsername)")
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/\(followerInfo.followerUsername)/followers") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.followers = decodedResponse.followers
                    }
                    
                    return
                }
            }
            
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct FollowersView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FollowersView()
    }
}
```

The code gets to `print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error")")` and prints "Unknown Error" before crashing. Upon inspecting the data that comes back, it comes up with nothing, at least not that I can tell anyway. (I'm not entirely accustomed to the Xcode debugger). I double checked the API response in a browser and the fields in the response in the browser and the names of the properties in the Codable struct match. So, I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: “The code gets to print” And what does it print?

Comment: It prints "Unknown Error"

Comment: Ok so I see what the problem is, thanks. There are two issues. First, you have no if/else, so you are printing the download  error even if there is no download error.

Comment: Second, you are saying try? so if there is a decoding  error (and there is) you throw away the info you need. Use try/catch instead and print the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly. Update your `Codable` as shown below:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - FollowerElement
struct FollowerElement: Codable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeID: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let gravatarID: String
    let url, htmlURL, followersURL: String
    let followingURL, gistsURL, starredURL: String
    let subscriptionsURL, organizationsURL, reposURL: String
    let eventsURL: String
    let receivedEventsURL: String
    let type: String
    let siteAdmin: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case gravatarID = "gravatar_id"
        case url
        case htmlURL = "html_url"
        case followersURL = "followers_url"
        case followingURL = "following_url"
        case gistsURL = "gists_url"
        case starredURL = "starred_url"
        case subscriptionsURL = "subscriptions_url"
        case organizationsURL = "organizations_url"
        case reposURL = "repos_url"
        case eventsURL = "events_url"
        case receivedEventsURL = "received_events_url"
        case type
        case siteAdmin = "site_admin"
    }
}

typealias Follower = [FollowerElement]
```

You can remove properties you don't need from above code.

Now update your `dataTask` method

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let data = data {
                
                do {
                    let follower = try JSONDecoder().decode(Follower.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print(follower.count)
                        }
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }.resume()
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you very much! I appreciate it!